# Need to modify the data in .xml file from the Excel Macro code

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have an .xml file with me. The code in the xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
<Table Id ="L2-MP3">
<Row>
<Parameter Name="TestID">1</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Scope">L2</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Description">m1dB_48K_16b_AP.wav</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Format">wma</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Input">c:\Data\Test\Standard\m1dB_48K_16b_AP.wav</Parameter>
<Parameter Name="Operation">15000,stop</Parameter>
</Row>
</Table>
</Data>
```

Here my requirement is, if you observe the description and the input part, there are some digits as 48, 16 and AP. not i need to fetch that values from the excel macro Module.

As i have the values ready in the Module, can any only please help me how to get the values into this .xml file. Also tell me how to construct the bridge between them and how to use the variables here in .xml file from the excel macro. and as shown 48, 16 and AP in that file are variable according to the requirement.

Your suggestion is very valuable for me.

I would be really thank full if you could help me in this regard?

Comment: [Here is a nice solution : Creating Excel Macro for Exporting XML to a certain folder ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142523/creating-excel-macro-for-exporting-xml-to-a-certain-folder?rq=1[link]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you import the XML in EXCEL
more information

[TUTORIAL : Import XML to an EXCEL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925108/extract-data-fields-from-xml-into-excel)

[the official site](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-use-xml-in-excel-2003-HA001101964.aspx)

and then try to seperate wanted piece parts of your input with the function MID in excel

[TUTORIAL : MID function in EXCEL](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/excel-mid-function/)

Hope that this solve your problem.

About the macro, sorry I'm looking for a similar solution
[EXCEL, create a XML-file from a data in table via vba code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25469367/excel-create-a-xml-file-from-a-data-in-table-via-a-macro)

(I found a solution : [Creating Excel Macro for Exporting XML to a certain folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142523/creating-excel-macro-for-exporting-xml-to-a-certain-folder?rq=1).)